# Detect press of "next track" button on keyboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, keyboard-events

I would like to be able to detect when the "next track," "previous track," and (where applicable) "shuffle" buttons on the user's keyboard. Is this even possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you know the key code you can. Although not all keyboards will have it, or perhaps will differ. (guessing)

see the keycode by doing this and hitting a key:

```
$(window).keydown( function(event){ console.log(event.keyCode); } );
```

when you have the code you can handle the event when that key is hit.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JyKMN/

Comment: For me, I get 176 for "next track" and 177 for "previous track." The "shuffle" key doesn't register at all. Is this universal or keyboard-specific? Thanks!

Comment: no idea, but on my Mac the browser doesn't even receive an event. Whatever you're trying to do I'd avoid relying on this. Perhaps use 37 and 39 (arrow keys)

Comment: Thanks. I'm definitely not relying on it, it's just a secondary control.

Comment: I just added a fiddle to the post.

Answer (score 4):

Actually this is possible now using the Media session feature provided by browser. normal keyboard events normally won't support the player control buttons in keyboard.
here's an example from [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API):

```js
if ('mediaSession' in navigator) {
  navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
    title: 'Unforgettable',
    artist: 'Nat King Cole',
    album: 'The Ultimate Collection (Remastered)',
    artwork: [
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/96x96',   sizes: '96x96',   type: 'image/png' },
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/128x128', sizes: '128x128', type: 'image/png' },
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/192x192', sizes: '192x192', type: 'image/png' },
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/256x256', sizes: '256x256', type: 'image/png' },
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/384x384', sizes: '384x384', type: 'image/png' },
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/512x512', sizes: '512x512', type: 'image/png' },
    ]
  });

  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('play', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('pause', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekbackward', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekforward', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('previoustrack', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('nexttrack', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
}
```

Please note that this feature is not supported in all browsers.

Comment: Nice. Thank you for this answer. This is the first time I have seen this feature described.

Comment: This does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find the shuffle `keyCode`, but this captures the fast forward and rewind... There has to be a better way of doing what you are trying to do than this IMO.

```
$('#capture').on('keydown',function(e){
    switch (e.which) {
        case 176:
            alert('Fast Forward');
            break;
        case 177:
            alert('Rewind');
            break;
        default:
            alert('Neither FF or rewind was pressed');  
            }      
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/XLEvx/1/)**